# Vagrant shared folder. Symlinks

Tags: virtualbox, chef-infra, vagrant

I am trying to figure out If I am capable of having symlinks in my shared folder when booting up a vm.

I currently have a project with a few symlinks in the library directory which I would like to edit on the fly and see the changes on the vm.

I can't seem to figure this out. I have a feeling it's not possible. The symlinks do not exist.

```
config.vm.share_folder "k5", "/projects", "/Users/slik/projects"
config.vm.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/v-root", "1"]
```

Comment: I am running into a similar issue. Has anyone found a fix for this yet?

Answer (score 11):

You just have to add the *setextradata* parameter for every shared folder mount.

```
config.vm.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/k5", "1"]
```

Comment: `k5` in this example is the shared folder name?

Comment: So, what is k5 in this example?

Comment: it is the shared folder name - Settings -> Shared Folders -> Name column

Comment: I guess so. I can't remember in detail 8 years later. But would be cool, if anyone here could post that info, once you've figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Or from the command line

```
VBoxManage setextradata <VM Name> VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/<volume> 1
```